# Degree of a pull back bundle on product manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds

For any Kähler manifold $(X^n,\omega)$ and a holomorphic line bundle $L$ on it, let's define the degree of $L$ to be $\int_X c_1(L)\wedge w^{n-1}$. Now let's take $(X,\omega_1)$ and $(Y,\omega_2)$ two compact Riemann surfaces with $\omega_1,\omega_2$ denoting the respective Kähler forms on them. Now say $L$ is a holomorphic line bundle on $X$, I want to see if deg $L$=deg $\pi_1^*(L)?$ We get
\begin{align*}
& \int_{X\times Y} c_1(\pi_1^* L)\wedge (\pi_1^*\omega_1+\pi_2^*\omega_2)\\
&=\int_{X\times Y}\pi_1^*c_1 (L)\wedge \pi_2^*\omega_2+\int_{X\times Y}\pi_1^*c_1 (L)\wedge \pi_1^*\omega_1\\
&=\int_{X\times Y}\pi_1^*c_1 (L)\wedge \pi_2^*\omega_2+\int_{X\times Y}\pi_1^*(c_1(L)\wedge\omega_1)\\
&=\int_{X\times Y}\pi_1^*c_1 (L)\wedge \pi_2^*\omega_2+0
\end{align*}

I want to use some form of Fubini to prove my guess but I am not totally sure how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You never defined $\pi_j$.

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry I thought it was obvious. $\pi_1:X\times Y\rightarrow X$ projection onto $X$ and $\pi_2:X\times Y\rightarrow Y$ projection onto $Y$.

Comment: @Partha Express what you have in terms of cohomology classes and apply the Künneth theorem?